# Is there a way I can dynamically define a Predicate body from a string containing the code?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, extension-methods

This is probably a stupid question, but here goes.  I would like to be able to dynamically construct a predicate < T > from a string parsed from a database VARCHAR column, or any string, for that matter.  For example, say the column in the database contained the following string:

```
return e.SomeStringProperty.Contains("foo");
```

These code/string values would be stored in the database knowing what the possible properties of the generic "e" is, and knowing that they had to return a boolean.  Then, in a magical, wonderful, fantasy world, the code could execute without knowing what the predicate was, like:

```
string predicateCode = GetCodeFromDatabase();
var allItems = new List<SomeObject>{....};
var filteredItems = allItems.FindAll(delegate(SomeObject e) { predicateCode });
```

or Lambda-ized:

```
var filteredItems = allItems.FindAll(e => [predicateCode]);
```

I know it can probably never be this simple, but is there a way, maybe using Reflection.Emit, to create the delegate code dynamically from text and give it to the FindAll < T > (or any other anonymous/extension) method?

Answer (score 1):

The C# and VB compilers are available from within the .NET Framework:

[C# CodeDom Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)

Be aware though, that this way you end up with a separate assembly (which can only be unloaded if it's in a separate AppDomain). This approach is only feasible if you can compile all the predicates you are going to need at once. Otherwise there is too much overhead involved.

System.Reflection.Emit is a great API for dynamically emitting code for the CLR. It is, however, a bit cumbersome to use and you must learn CIL.

LINQ expression trees are an easy to use back-end (compilation to CIL) but you would have to write your own parser.

I suggest you have a look at one of the "dynamic languages" that run on the CLR (or DLR) such as [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython). It's the most efficient way to implement this feature, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Dynamic Linq project it does all this and more!

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Great for simple stuff like user selected orderby's or where clauses

Comment: Nice of you to make this community wiki, but I couldn't find anything relating to "Dynamic Link project" to provide some context to your answer.  Can you please add a URL?

Comment: The problem with Dynamic Linq (so far as I can tell) is that I wouldn't be able to use any complex, non-SQL code in the Predicate.  The "allItems" list is not a database-bound object, it's a list of strings, actually, that I'd like to be able to test in various ways not defined in the source code.

Comment: That would be Dynamic Linq :-) not Link

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

also

http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/15/dynamic-linq/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [emit](http://www.devhood.com/Tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=238), but you'd be building your own parser.

**EDIT**

I remember that in ScottGu's PDC keynote, he showed a feature using the CLI version of the .net framework that resembled Ruby's eval, but I can't find a URL that can corroborate this.  I'm making this a commnity wiki so that anyone who has a good link can add it.

Comment: The link you provided isn't for C# 4.0, it's for Mono 2.2.

Comment: You're right. I removed the link and put in the edited comments.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped off the dynamic linq because it's limited in ways I want to search a collection, unless you prove me wrong.

My filter needs to be: in a list of orders, filter the list so that I have only the orders with in the collection of items in that order, an item with the name "coca cola".

So that will result to a method of: `orders.Findall(o => o.Items.Exists(i => i.Name == "coca cola"))`

In dynamic linq I didn't find any way to do that, so I started with `CodeDomProvicer`.
I created a new `Type` with a method which contains my dynamically built `FindAll` Method:

```
public static IList Filter(list, searchString)
{
   // this will by dynamically built code
   return orders.Findall(o => o.Items.Exists(i => i.Name == "coca cola"));
}
```

when I try to build this assembly:

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sb.ToString());
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid expression term ">"
```

Why isn't the compiler able to compile the predicate?